# Best way to make a image grid? All same size and dimensions

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a photo grid for the reference web page, what would be the best method? so far I have managed to get the photos sort-of alined, but i have a problem as they are different sizes. how to reshape them all equal? would i need to use photoshop? any tips, papa bless.

https://jsfiddle.net/12bv63h8/
example https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUEkS.jpg

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Referenzen </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">           
   <h1 align="center">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a>
</h1>       
   <div class="menu_div">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="info.html">Info</a>
   <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>  
</li>      
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a>
   <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
   <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
   <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
</li>
</div>
   <div class="fadein"> 
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png"> 
</div>     

   <div class="floated_img">
   <ul>
   <li><img src="despraz_logo.GIF" alt="Despraz SA Logo"/></li>
</ul>      
<ul>
   <li><img src="caliqua_logo.gif" alt="Caliqua Logo"/></li>
</ul>    
<ul>
   <li><img src="bacher_logo.gif" alt="Bacher Logo"/></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><img src="bwt_logo.jpg" alt="BWT Logo"/></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><img src="engie-logo.jpg" alt="Engine Logo"/></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><img src="halg_logo.jpg" alt="Halg Logo"/></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><img src="johnson_controls_logo.jpg" alt="Johson Controls Logo"/></li>
</ul>    
</div>       
</body> 
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body { font-family: verdana; background:white ; color: black; }


}

.menu_div{background-color: #333; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

    .fadein { position:absolute; height:500px; width:49px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }

.menu_div { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color: #333


}
.fadein { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3; 
  background: ;
  width: 100%;
  left: -0.5px;
  top: 0em;


  }

.fadein img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 4060px;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-height: 400%;
}




.tech-slideshow {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/collage.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow:hover .mover-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-66.6666%);  
  }
}


form {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;

  /* Just to center the form on the page */
  margin:  auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* To see the limits of the form */
  padding: 10em;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

label {
  /* To make sure that all label have the same size and are properly align */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  text-align: left;
}

input, textarea {
  /* To make sure that all text field have the same font settings
     By default, textarea are set with a monospace font */
  font: 1em verdana;

  /* To give the same size to all text field */
  width: 200px;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;

  /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
  border: 2px solid ;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  /* To give a little highligh on active elements */
  border-color: black;
}

textarea {
  /* To properly align multiline text field with their label */
  vertical-align: top

  /* To give enough room to type some text */
  height: 23em;

  /* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
     It works only on Chrome, Firefox and Safari */
  resize: vertical;
}

.button {
  /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
  padding-left: 400px; /* same size as the label elements */
}

button {
  /* This extra magin represent the same space as the space between
     the labels and their text fields */
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}

.image-upload img
{
    width: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;

}



.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;  
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    text-align: center;
    border: -0.2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.flex-container > * {
    padding: 150px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 110%;
    flex: 1 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid #CCCCCC;
    height: 200px:
}

.article {
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:11px
}

header {
background: white;color:black;
font-size: 0.9em;
}


footer {background: #333;color:white;
position: absolute;
bottom: -641px;
width: 1117px;

}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav {text-align:left;-webkit-flex: 1 auto;flex:1 auto;-webkit-order:1;order:1;}
    .article {-webkit-flex:5 0px;flex:5 0px;-webkit-order:2;order:2;}
    footer {-webkit-order:3;order:3;}
}



.indexinfo {

padding:70px;
-webkit-flex: 1 100%;
flex: 1 110%;
height: 70px;
border: px solid black;
height: 200px:
text: center;

}

.sidebar-image-gallery { 

height: 700px;
width: 1323px;

}


    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.floated_img
{
    float: center;
    padding: .5rem;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have individual UL for each image? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a `position` and `transform` logic to make different sized images to look the same using this code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.thumbnails {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnails li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnails li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li>
    <img src="https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/imagecache/inline-small/inline/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/83/90/0a/83900a5b6d403ddbfd4e843ea70828f4.jpg" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/redux/master/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman/batman-logo-big.gif" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Beats_Electronics_logo.svg/2000px-Beats_Electronics_logo.svg.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/UD-KASEmF9tLG5TaqmEQQL_LJrc=/fit-in/1200x9600/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F122081%2FS-Skype-logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d3/Starbucks_Corporation_Logo_2011.svg/1017px-Starbucks_Corporation_Logo_2011.svg.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/58/Pepsi_logo.svg/1280px-Pepsi_logo.svg.png" alt="Logo">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @AJOnline Glad I could help.. `:D`

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox to the rescue!

```
<ul class="flexMe">
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
   <li><img src="img.gif" alt=" "/></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.flexMe{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexMe li{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.flexMe li img{
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

What we are doing here is creating a grid layout with `flexbox` to get everything positioned nicely and then we are using `flexbox` again on the `li` elements to position the images centrally within the frame at 100% width

Answer (score 1):

i recommend the  Masonry JS library to display images of different sizes

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html